# Calling a method of MainActivity from other class

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app and thus, I have a `MainActivity` class. Inside of that `MainActivity` class, I have a method, let's call it `doSomething()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void doSomething(){
        // bla bla bla
    }
}
```

I also have a different class (with different layout) that is called `OtherActivity`. I want to use the `doSomething` method inside it:

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity_layout);

        // Let's use doSomething()
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MainActivity main;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity_layout);

        // Let's use doSomething()
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But it does not work. I also tried to make `OtherActivity` to extend the `MainActivity`, doing the following:

```
public class OtherActivity extends MainActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity_layout);

        // Let's use doSomething()
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But it does not allow me to initialize the layout...

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `doSomething` do exactly?  Is it something that should live in a utility class, or does sub-classing actually make sense here?  What happens in the sub-class example, and what did you expect?

Comment: I'm working with a code programmed from another guy... and I don't think that including that method inside the MainActivity is a good practice.

The method just takes the value of a global variable and launchs different activities depending on that value using a switch.

Comment: I would create a BaseActivity that could be extended by both MainActivity and OtherActivity. You only need to add and store your doSomething() method along with the global variables in the BaseActivity so both MainActivity and OtherActivity could access them. Don't forget to extend AppCompatActivity in BaseActivity. Something like this: "BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity" + "MainActivity extends BaseActivity" + "OtherActivity extends BaseActivity".

Comment: By global, do you mean a member variable of `MainActivity`?  In this case both examples would fail, since you aren't using the original instance of `MainActivity` so that 'global' would likely have the wrong value.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Yeah, but it's not exactly that. The original method uses a member variable of `MainActivity', but I olverloaded it creating the same method with one parameter. I specify the parameter inside `OtherActivity'

Comment: @VíctorMartínez while that doesn't sound like the greatest design, but that *should* work, so hard to say what's wrong without seeing more code.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I think that the problem when `OtherActivity' extends `MainActivity' arises when I do `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);'. It does not load the `other_activity_layout'. Neither it loads `activity_main' layout... The app just keeps blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To communicate between to Activity Broadcast is the best way, and for the same application, we can use local broadcast using LocalBroadcastManager.

First, we should register one broadcast in MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "do_some_action";
    public static final String INTENT_BUNDLE_VALUE = "value1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mChangeListener, new IntentFilter(INTENT_FILTER));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mChangeListener);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mChangeListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intentData) {
            // you can do anything here
            if (intentData != null && intentData.hasExtra(INTENT_BUNDLE_VALUE)) {
                String value = intentData.getStringExtra(INTENT_BUNDLE_VALUE);

                doSomeAction(value);
            }
        }
    };
    private void doSomeAction(String value) {

    }
}
```

Then to do some action in MainActivity from OtherActivity, we can send Local broadcast from OtherActivity it will reach the receiver of Which we register in MainActivity,

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        // You can call MainActivity to do some actions
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.INTENT_FILTER);

        intent.putExtra(MainActivity1.INTENT_BUNDLE_VALUE, "Any string or any value");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Done!!!.

Comment: How can I pass a String inside the Broadcast in order to receive it in `private BroadcastReceiver mChangeListener = new BroadcastReceiver()´?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, I'm going to make a static navigator to handle your navigation logic.  If you are opposed to static methods you could also make them on your `Application` object to make it easier to manage dependencies, I'm just making it static for simplicity.

```
//Making this fully static for simplicity, this is fine for a small app
//you can make it a singleton on the application class for more flexibility
public class Navigator {
    //static member vars that determine navigation
    // pass in Context if needed for navigation purposes
    public static void doSomething(Context context){ 
        // bla bla bla
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        Navigator.doSomething(this);
    }
}

public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_activity_layout);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        Navigator.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it needed to declare a Navigator nav = new Navigator(); before calling it in Navigator.doSomething(this)?

Comment: It's declared static, so you don't need an instance.

Comment: Inside doSomething, I will launch several activites. I need an onActivityResult method too. Could it be inside Navigator too?

Comment: You can override the method on each activity to call into the navigator to do things sure.